Data with a limited window
I am working on my master thesis, but I am kind of stuck.
I did a questionnaire about how much desire there is to have a certain product and what factors play the biggest role in their desirability, with the data looking like this:
Want.the.product-factor 1 - factor 2  - factor 3 - .... - factor 10
50 persons  gave every factor + want the product points out of 5 (so they don't rank them, the answer for each of them can be 5).
I tried using a normal lm(Want.the.product~factor 1 - factor 2  - factor 3 - .... - factor 10)
But there was no significance, I am thinking this is because the data goes from 1 to 5, but I have no way how to go about analyzing this differently.

What is your research question? What does this data represent? How is it coded?

I can say even if you did get some results that you think might be sensible, I doubt a linear model would be an appropriate fit since your "want the product" measure is on an ordinal scale and hence, your model error is not likely to be normally distributed as required in a linear regression model.

@Stats It is the exceptional linear regression that requires or assumes model error is normally distributed. // Sam: your data cannot identify ten factors with just fifty observations.  That would be overfitting.  Have you researched the process of model identification or related techniques like regularization, glmnet, Lasso, Ridge Regression, etc.?

@whuber Thank your for the answer, sadly the statistics I have gotten in school is bare bones and a linear model is about as for as my knowledge reaches. I have however tried to put the factors in a PCR and this seem to get some results, is this overfitting aswell?

@whuber, yes, fair point. I should have been clearer.
